# Mockito verify() failing for LiveData postValue

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing, android-architecture-navigation

I have created a LoginFragment which navigates to another one when a login is successful using the Navigation Architecture Component. Works fine but the test for it is failing. It is quite a close mirror of the GithubBrowser sample and my test is very similar to the `clickRepo` test [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserFragmentTest.kt), except I am testing that a new page is loaded when a successful Resource is posted instead of upon a click.

Error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
navController.navigate(
app.ui.login.LoginFragmentDirections$ShowSelectMerchant@377f3c27
);
```

LoginFragmentTest.kt

```
@Test
fun success(){
    val user = TestUtil.createUser(email)

    userData.postValue(Resource.success(user))

    System.out.println("Test NavController Hash: " + testFragment.navController.hashCode())
            verify(testFragment.navController).navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.showSelectMerchant().matcher())

}
```

LoginFragment.kt

```
override fun openSelectMerchantFragment() {
    System.out.println("Real NavController Hash: " + navController().hashCode())
    navController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.showSelectMerchant())
}
```

`openSelectMerchantFragment` is called when a successful Resource is posted to the live userData. Is there an obvious reason why the test is failing?

I can see that the test fragment's mocked nav controller and the one that is called in the fragment itself have the same hash value so I am pretty sure it's not a problem with how I have mocked the activity, fragment or nav controller. I can also obviously see that the navigate() function is definitely called.

Comment: Are you using [CountingTaskExecutorRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/CountingTaskExecutorRule)? That's necessary if you're using `postValue`

Comment: Thanks Ian but that ain't my problem. I had forgotten the `TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule` rule, but interestingly my other tests which use `postValue` pass without it, as do _all_ of the tests in the GithubBrowserSample's entire `UserFragmentTest`. So that's another question in itself, this is going to require some digging :)

Comment: Thought I had figured it out in that I was missing a call to `matcher()` which the sample uses to mock the Nav arguments but that hasn't made any difference either (I have no args anyway).

Comment: Retitled the question so it is more apt - calling drainTasks to allow the posting to finish seems to be the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was a simple one of testing LiveData as Ian suggests. It is not enough to add a `TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule`, but `drainTasks()` must be called to allow the data posting to complete. I can't answer why it works in the sample's entire test class without any call to `drainTasks`, my best guess is that the posting in those tests simply complete fast enough for it to not be an issue. I *think* it is good practice to always call `drainTasks` whenever a live data is posted to.

Final result:

```
@Test
fun success(){
    val user = TestUtil.createUser(email)

    userData.postValue(Resource.success(user))
    executorRule.drainTasks(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    verify(testFragment.navController).navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.showSelectMerchant().matcher())
}
```

Comment: Came across the same problem today while following along with the github repo sample. Strangely enough most of my `postValue` tests work without calling drain tasks, it was only the navigation tests that didn't. Feel free to mark this as correct answer